# Trying to create a simple coin, but getting warnings for the last two functions. Can you find and solve the error?

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Bubblecoin{


    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    uint  supply;

    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint){
        return supply;

    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance){
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success){

        if (balances[msg.sender] >= tokens && tokens >=0){
            balances[msg.sender]-= tokens;
            balances[to] += tokens;

            return true;

        }

        else {

            return false;
        }
     }

    function mint(uint numberOfCoin){
        balances[msg.sender] += numberOfCoin;
        supply += numberOfCoin;

    }

    function getMyBalance() returns (uint){
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd help if you posted what the warnings actually were. I'm almost certain that if it's just warnings...its probably alluding to defining if these are `public` or `private` functions and the second one is also a `view`.

Comment: Can you provide me your email address? I will share with you the screenshots, and also a few more basic doubts. It will be embarrassing if I ask those here.

Comment: I would actually put those questions here. Nothing is an embarrassing question if it's well thought out on StackExchange. Edit your question and include the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> browser/SomeCoin.sol:34:5: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
>     function mint(uint numberOfCoin){
>     ^
> Spanning multiple lines.
> ```

Because you didn't mention visibility of method public, private or internal.

I am just giving overview of access specifiers like:

1. public: If you specified method as public, anyone (Contract/Web3js) can call your method.
2. internal: If you specified method as internal, only contract inherited can access your memory variables or functions. This is more useful to write common code and extends contract A to contract B.
3. private: If you specified method as private, only current contract access your memory variables or functions. This is more useful when you want to protect your logic to outside of contract.

Coming to above warning: Compiler saying by default your method is public visibility. That means your method is visible to outside your contract. Solidity compiler is giving waring because by mistake you might missed access specifier.

Comment: @kamalYadav Let me know your any doubts.